# How to access the async/await scope variable out of the async function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to use `cafesList` and `placeList` variables out of the async/await function so that I can pass these two variables containing array of objects to another function where I will combine these two variables data in a single array of objects.

I have tried to declare these two variables as global and tried to utilize outside but getting output like the following -

`Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: undefined`

But when `fetchCafes()` and `fetchPlaces()` called directly, these functions yield array of objects as result.

This is the fetch api method -

```
function sendHttpRequest(method, url) {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: method,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        return response.json().then((errData) => {
          console.log(errData);
          throw new Error("Something went wrong! - Server Side");
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
    });
}
```

These are the two async/await method containing `cafesList` and `placeList` variable -

```
async function fetchCafes() {
  try {
    const cafesList = await sendHttpRequest(
      "GET",
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/debojyoti/places-fake-rest-api/master/cafes.json"
    );
    console.log(cafesList);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}

async function fetchPlaces() {
  try {
    const placeList = await sendHttpRequest(
      "GET",
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/debojyoti/places-fake-rest-api/master/places.json"
    );
    console.log(placeList);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should **`return`** them so that the promise fulfills with these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that cutting it for you?

Return the data from the functions:

```
async function fetchCafes() {
    try {
        const cafesList = await sendHttpRequest(
            "GET",
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/debojyoti/places-fake-rest-api/master/cafes.json"
        );
        console.log(cafesList);
        return cafesList;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}

async function fetchPlaces() {
    try {
        const placeList = await sendHttpRequest(
            "GET",
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/debojyoti/places-fake-rest-api/master/places.json"
        );
        console.log(placeList);
        return placeList;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

Call the two functions and wait for them to finish. Then handle the results:

```
Promise.all([fetchCafes(), fetchPlaces()]).then(arr => {
    const cafes = arr[0];
    const places = arr[1];
    // merge them here...
});
```

Comment: then how can I receive the combined array from the merge function ? if the merge function return an array? For this do I need to use Promise block again ? the return result from the merge function can be used for searching inside another function and that search function search on every keystroke event listener.. So if you can give me an idea about how to handle the return result of the merge function it will be very helpful..thank you